# Generate a random string on startup only once (Reference to an instance?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, static

As part of a user-awareness-test with anonymized results i want to generate a random encryption salt everytime the server is restarted.

I tried to import the module that defines a variable with a random value, but everytime i call it it generates a new one. I need the variable to stay the same as long the server is running.

Is it possible to set a reference to the already running module (so the variable stays the same) or define a global variable with a random value that wont change during runtime?

Comment: Add your code, please.

Comment: I already got it, thank you! I used the `hash()` alghorithm of python. In version 3.x theres an option that generates different hashes, once the session is restarted. This option is turned on by default from python version 3 and higher.

Comment: To give some value to this question for the whole community you should add the code that contains your problem, post an answer with the code that solves the problem and accept it. Otherwise I recommend deleting this question.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `hash()` alghorithm of python. In version 3.x theres an option that generates a different hash out of the same object once the session is restarted. This option is turned on by default from python version 3 and higher. That was exactly what i need.